# Cyclic group of direct product

Tags: group-theory

I know that $Z_m \times Z_n$ is cyclic and isomorphic to $Z_{mn}$ if and only if $\gcd(m,n)=1$. There is also a corollary that saying "The group $Z_{m_1} \times Z_{m_2} \times Z_{m_3} \times \ldots \times Z_{m_i}$ is cyclic and isomorphic to $Z_{m_1 m_2 \ldots m_i}$ if and only if any two of $m_i$'s are relatively prime. Why is that so? Shouldn't all of them be relatively prime? For example, according to this corollary,$Z_4 \times Z_3 \times Z_{10}$ must be isomorphic to $Z_{120}$, but it is not. So, what is the correct version of this corollary?

Thank you

Comment: It seems that the conditions "any two of mi's are relatively prime" and "all of them are relatively prime" are equvivalent.

Comment: The $m_i$'s must be pairwise coprime

Comment: oh, so i understood the sentence wrong, right? It is saying that if we take any two of them, then these must be relatively prime, and so all of them are relatively prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is correct.

In your "counter"-example it is not true that *any two of $m_i$'s are relatively prime*, because $\gcd(4,10)\ne 1$, and indeed $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_{10}\ncong\Bbb Z_{120}$, so it is all correct.

Comment: so i understood the sentence wrong, right? It is saying that if we take any two of them, then these must be relatively prime, and so all of them are relatively prime

Comment: Yes, any two of them: so they are "pairwise coprime", which is a stronger condition (as the example shows) than "all of them" has greatest common divisor $1$.